# Prove $(A^2-A)^2=0 \wedge (A^3+A^2-2A)=0 \implies A^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $(A^2-A)^2=0$ and $A^3+A^2-2A=0$ then $A^2=A$.

Any hint is a great help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: My prof told us there is a mistake in the problem. I can't even distinguish which it is so I don't know where to start but I do get the idea how to do it.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the
others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In
particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question
to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2):

$0=(A^2-A)^2 =A^4-2A^3+A^2$ and $0 = A(A^3+A^2-2A) = A^4+A^3-2A^2$. Thus, $3A^3 = 3A^2$, which implies $A^3 = A^2$ and so $2A^2-2A = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$(A^2-A)^2=0$ implies the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ divides $(x^2-x)^2$. Also by second hypothesis, $m_A(x)$ divides $x^3+x^2-2x$. Thus $m_A(x)$ divides its gcd also,namely, $x(x-1)=x^2-x$. Thus $(x^2-x)=m_A(x).h(x)$ for some $h$ and hence $$A^2-A=m_A(A) \cdot h(A) \equiv0$$